# creating triggers in java db

Tags: java, mysql, derby

I have been researching on creating Triggers in java db, actually I am developing a desktop application, and I want to be able to package it so that it can be installed on other users computers without them having to install a DBMS.
I know of how to create triggers in MYSql db, but packaging a java application with mysql is kinda complicated as compared to packaging one that uses Java DB but I haven't found a clear way of creating triggers in java db that fires after or before insert, update and delete. Is there anyone who has a clear way out, your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it's pretty much the same: [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Apache Derby documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html) for triggers you can find everything you asked for.